# c/C++ Why sometimes underscore why sometimes no underscore?!

Tags: c++

I've this header :

```
namespace Mem
{
  void init(void);
  void uninit(void);
  void *realloc(void *old, SIZE_T size);
  void *alloc(SIZE_T size);
  void free(void *mem);
  void freeArrayOfPointers(void *mem, SIZE_T count);
  void ASM_INTERNAL_DEF _copy(void *dest, const void *source, SIZE_T size);
  void _copyFromEnd(void *dest, const void *source, SIZE_T size);
  void *copyEx(const void *source, SIZE_T size);
  int _compare(const void *mem1, const void *mem2, SIZE_T size);
  void _zero(void *mem, SIZE_T size);
  void ASM_INTERNAL_DEF _set(void *mem, char c, SIZE_T size);
  void *_getL(void *mem, char c, SIZE_T size);
  void *_getR(void *mem, char c, SIZE_T size);
  void _replace(void *mem, SIZE_T size, char oldChar, char newChar);
  void *_findData(const void *mem, SIZE_T memSize, void *data, SIZE_T dataSize);
  void _swap(void *mem1, void *mem2, SIZE_T size);
  SIZE_T _replaceDword(DWORD originalValue, DWORD newValue, void *mem, SIZE_T memSize);
};
```

what mean function that which have underscore?? and no underscore?
Thx.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Comment: @nabeel, None of these names violate those rules.

Comment: I'm going to take a guess that the ones with leading underscores are used internally and are not meant to be used from outside code.

Answer (score 1):

In the identifiers you have shown, the underscore bears no special meaning. It is simply part of the function name.